# Error 404 (Not Found) al publicar imágenes/iconos tipo SVG a un Hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, svg

mi aplicación web la estoy subiendo en el Hosting de SmarterASP.net, la dirección del archivo esta bien puesto que tengo imágenes en png que tiene el mismo criterio de ruta y trabaja bien.

El error que me sale es:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)."
http://system....Content/fonts/icomoon.ttf?rb2q00 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Mi proyecto en localhost se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el Hosting de Smarterasp:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vi por hay que puede ser un problema de IIS, y que poniendo este codigo en el web.config se arreglaría pero en mi caso lo empeoro:

```
<system.webServer>    
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
....
```

así mando a llamar al arcihivo svg:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:    url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?rb2q00');
src:    url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?rb2q00#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf?rb2q00') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.woff?rb2q00') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?rb2q00#icomoon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Please, ¿alguien me podría decir que pasa y que podría hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Las URLs son relativas, por lo tanto cuando llamas al archivo utiliza como base el lugar desde donde la llamas (parece ser que es una plantilla .css) y probablemente no la encuentre donde le indicas.

Una solución recomendable es declarar en la cabecera la URL base en tu html:

```
<head>
   <base href="http://misitio.com/">
</head>
```

Así podrás asignar cualquier dirección relativa al directorio principal...

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'icomoon';
src: url('/fonts/icomoon.eot');
```

Suponiendo que los fonts estén '/fonts' del directorio principal y el font en cuestión se llame 'icomoon.eot'.

Otra solución es poner los archivos buscados en el mismo directorio que la plantillas .css y simplemente 'url(icomoon.eot)'

Answer (score 0):

estas usando una dirección `../` para acceder al archivo que contiene la fuente. En tu servidor remoto eso normalmente no funciona, por eso te sale la dirección

```
http://system...Contents
```

Prueba a cambiar la dirección de la fuente a la ruta desde la raíz de tu sitio web. Por ejemplo si las fuentes las tienes en `/css/fonts` prueba a cargar la fuente `url('css/fonts/')`